# Safety difference between adding a PPA and manually installing a deb package

Tags: package-management, software-installation, security, ppa

I would like difference with regard to safety between installing software by adding a PPA or by using a .deb package.

For example, I found a specific application in GitHub and I want to install it. The instructions to install include two options:

Option 1 - Via PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ppaName
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software Name
```

Option 2 - From Package

```
wget https://github.com/path/to/software/download/v1.0/SoftwareName.deb
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi SoftwareName.deb
```

Since the [reliability of a PPA depends of many factors](https://askubuntu.com/a/35636/437173), is safer install it by downloading a deb package?

Are there any safety differences between these two methods?

Comment: In most cases you will not find deb files in github.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you trust the provider, it's OK to install from PPA. The advantage of getting software from PPA is that you get automatic updates, which doesn't happen if you install from a Debian (.deb) package.

About security, there isn't much difference between one method and another. If you install an X package through PPA using `apt-get`, what happens is basically the download of its .deb and its installation with `dpkg`.

So, overall, it's better to use PPA over manual installation, due to automatic updates.

Comment: Automatic updates may be not good if a maintainer pushes a buggy version. like I do sometimes ;-)

Comment: In the other hand, in most cases automatic updates bring important security/bug fixes and new features.